# Google Client PHP API ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE Error

Tags: php, error-handling, google-api, google-api-client, google-oauth

I am having a very difficult time trying to track down an error when calling Googles `$client->refreshToken()`.

The server is returning a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE 324 run time error, but I cant seem to catch the error.

Here is my code:

```
$ref = $this->client->getRefreshToken();
try {
    $this->client->refreshToken($ref); // <<<<<<<<<<<<ERROR HERE
} catch (\Exception $e) {
     if($debug){
        print_r( $e ); 
        print_r( $this ); 
     }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a recently published an update to the NSS package for CentOS 7 systems which was resulting in an Aache error

```
/usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libnsssysinit.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure
```

The issue was resolved by restarting the Apache and FPM services.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your httpd/apache service and everything should be fine! If you want to restart without interrupptions, apachectl graceful should be fine enough:

```
apachectl graceful
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting HTTPD service worked for AWS-EC2 server.

1. Login as root user

$sudo su

2. Restart HTTPD

$service httpd restart